# problems with LD_LIBRARY_PATH

Tags: linux, google-colaboratory

this command in Google Colab: `LD_LIBRARY_PATH=!./:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ...` produce that error:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=!./:[/bin/bash: !./:[/bin/bash: ./:/usr/lib64-nvidia: No such file or directory]: No such file or directory]!./uselib data/obj.names cfg/yolo-obj.cfg /my_drive/backup/yolo-obj_4000.weights /my_drive/test_videos/video_test.mp4
```

how can I fix it?

Comment: do you know why you are using a `!` char? (Is that documented?) , Normally that is an escape char for cmd-line history references (`!!` being the most common, i.e. execute the previous command from history). To help us debug, please and an `echo "LD_LIBRARY_PATH=XXX${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"XXX` before the command is failing. copy/paste the output of that `echo` into the body of your question, using the `{}` tool from the Edit menu on that mouse-selected text to format correctly as `code/data/output/errMsgs`. Good luck.

Comment: hi @shellter i did, but the ! char it is used to make Colab understand jupyter that it is a linux command

Comment: Sorry, I don't know anything about `Colab`, but it's hard to understand how a system that knows it is sending a cmd to `linux` is going to use a well-know *xxxescapexxx* **meta** char. AND even more curious as to how putting a! char embedded inside the cmd is supposed to work. Maybe `!LD_LIB... =...::$LD_LIB...` makes more sense? Otherwise you'll have to hope a true `Colab `user can help solve your problem. Maybe they have their own support forum? Good luck. (Small edit, ~2 hrs later, `s/escape/meta/`).